# есть ли возможность открыть sql файл средствами php?

Tags: php, sql

Можно ли как нибудь прочитать sql файл? Имеется ввиду прочитать содержание базы? 
Например я экспортировал таблицу в sql файл, а в php хочу получить содержимое этой таблицы (название полей, значения в этих полях).
Гугл не дал результатов по этому поводу, вот и возник вопрос возможно ли это?

Comment: экспортируйте в файл `data.csv` и читайте средствами php: `$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));`

Comment: напишите это в ответ, я подтвержу. А это единственный вариант? именно с форматом sql нет возможности?

Comment: Если вы хотите готовую функцию, которая бы разобрала sql, то ее конечно в php нет. Но PHP это полный по Тьюрингу язык и значит на нем можно сделать вообще все что угодно. Надо написать небольшой синтаксический парсер, который разберет SQL. учитывая, что вам нужно брать из дампа БД, то вам достаточно разобрать фразу insert после которой имя таблицы и колонок и блок values с значениями. думаю в пару десятков строк можно уложиться

Comment: Зачем? SQL запросы в базу уже не модно?

Comment: https://github.com/greenlion/PHP-SQL-Parser/wiki/Parser-Manual посмотрите этот парсер sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Экспортируйте данные в файл `*.csv` и читайте штатными средствами php:

1. [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php)

Пример использования:

```
$file_csv = 'data.csv';

if (($fh = fopen($file_csv, 'r')) !== false) {
    $csv = [];
    while (($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false) {
        $csv[] = $row;
    }
    fclose($fh);
    var_dump($csv);
}
```

2. [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-getcsv.php)

Пример использования:

```
$file_csv = 'data.csv';

if (file_exists($file_csv)) {
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file_csv));
    var_dump($csv);
}
```

Оба варианта возвращают один и тот же массив данных.

> *А это единственный вариант? Именно с форматом sql нет возможности?*

Нет, не единственный, но наверное самый удобный, т.к. для того же sql, как было сказано в комментарии, понадобится дополнительно писать парсер.

Ещё можно экспортировать данные в *.xml, но этот формат занимает больше места на диске, т.к. кроме основных данных из БД, в xml-файле хранится множество xml-тегов.

Comment: Получил массив таким способом, использовав формат csv
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['sqlFile']['tmp_name']);
$file = explode(';', $file);

Comment: @AntonKucenko да, так тоже можно, но на сколько удобным будет доступ к данным в файле? В csv в том и преимущество, что данные получаются структурированы, без комментариев и т.п. строк.

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать про csv , и последний вопрос. А как получить название полей?

Comment: @AntonKucenko чтоб в csv были включены названия полей, нужно при экспорте выбрать в селекте пункт `CSV for MS Excel`, и в цикле, там где идёт чтение файла, добавить два парметра, т.е. вместо этого `while (($row = fgetcsv($fh)) !== false)` нужно записать так: `while (($row = fgetcsv($fh, 0, ';')) !== false)`. В нулевом ключе результирующего массива вы получите названия полей.